Imaginary quadratic fields with class group of even order
Given the ring of integers created by adding the square root of $-d$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ for some positive integer $d$, is there a characterization of $d$ for when the class group of that ring has a size that is even? I was looking through the class numbers generated using variations of the code at Groovy Primes to Squares, and I noticed that there seems to be a pattern. I have searched elsewhere on the web for either easily executable code or large lists of class group computations, and I have not found anything, so I wrote my own.
In particular, I noticed that for $d$ divisible by $5$, the class number (the size of the class group) was always even. Is this always true? If $d$ is divisible by $5$, is the class number always even?
Since groups of even order always have an element of order $2$, this question can be put a different way. Is it true that for the equation $x^2 + 5d\cdot{y^2}$ with $x$ and $y$ positive integers and a fixed positive integer $d$, is there always a prime $p$ such that $p$ cannot be expressed by such an equation, but $p^2$ (the prime squared) can be expressed by such an equation?

I believe the answer to the question is given by On the class group of an imaginary quadratic number field. It seems that others have already asked a more sophisticated version of this question.
In summary I believe this to be true. The class number can be odd only if $d$ is a prime or a power of a prime where the class number was odd for the prime.

your conditions cause there to be more than one genus, so that the form class number is even. With $x^2 + 5 y^2$ you also get $2 x^2 + 2xy + 3 y^2.$  Take any prime $ p =2 x^2 + 2xy + 3 y^2,$  it cannot be represented by $u^2 + 5 v^2,$  but $p^2$ is,  by composition...see if you can find $u,v$  such that $u^2 + 5 v^2 = (2 x^2 + 2xy + 3 y^2)^2 $
